# How do you link a menu to a table from a query?

Tags: coldfusion

From the menu I have

```
<cfset temp =valuelist(GetDeptNum.csedept_name)>
<cfset ChangedElement = ListGetAt(temp, 2)>
<cfset TempToo = ListSetAt(temp, 2, ",")>
<cfdump var=#TempToo#>
<li class="fullChild"><a  id="corporate" href="phonelistsearch_test.cfm?corporate"  onclick="changeClass('corporate')" >Corporate</a><a class="opener"></a>
  <ul>
  <cfloop From = "1" To = "#ListLen(temptoo)#" INDEX = "Counter">
    <cfoutput><li> #ListGetAt(temptoo, Counter)#
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
   </ul>

</li>
```

I have a table which I use a filter to search the table, working, see http://jsfiddle.net/45grrk3m/ .

How would I link it to a table so when I click on the plus sign I can choose different choices 
and it will only filter those rows in that csedept_name I click?

Both tables GetUsers and GetDeptNum share the csedept_id collumn.

So from the menu dropdown I get the name right now which works GetDeptNum.csedept_name,
but not sure how I can make the connection between the menu and table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how you're generating the table.

Each option in your table should be a hyperlink back to the page (or ajax....) which passes the option selected. Your SQL query would then refine the search, and the table is recreated using the refined resulty